# jQuery overall index from parent element with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

How i can use the jQuery [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to find the index of a parent element with a certain class related to the whole document by a click on a link inside this element?

The following code does not work and returns -1 and i would like to know the index of the div element with the class "navi" in the document...

JavaScript

```
$('.navi').on('click', 'a.link', function(event) {
 var parent = $(this).closest('.navi');
 var index = $(document).index(parent);
 console.log(index);
 return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<html>
 ...
 <body>
  ...
  <div class="navi">
   ...
   <div class="anotherdiv">
    ...
    <a href="#" class="link"></a>
    ...
   </div>
   ...
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="navi">...</div>
  ...
 </body>
<html/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.navi').on('click', 'a.link', function(event) {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.navi');
    var index = $('.navi').index(parent[0]);
    console.log(index);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the selector from document to ".navi", like so:

```
var index = $('.navi').index(parent);
```

At the minute, you're trying to find the index of the element within the document (which is a collection of 1, in which navi doesn't exist).  What you really want to do is find where the element lives within a collection of elements with the .navi class which the above does.